# Call a function when INotifyPropertyChanged - UWP c#

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm calling a function in every minute which assigns values to an observable collection of SelectedSchoolList. I want to call another function (ex: CallIfValueChanged();) if any of data changed in this observable collection. How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
  public static ObservableCollection<SelectedSchoolList> _SelectedSchoolList = new ObservableCollection<SelectedSchoolList>();

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        // callback runs on UI thread
       async void  dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
        response_from_server = await CallWebService();
        if (!response_from_server.Equals("FAIL", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
        parseJSONandAssignValuesToSelectedSchoolList (response_from_server);//this function assigns values to _SelectedSchoolList  
        }                                 
        }
      CallIfValueChanged();// I want to call this function here only if any data on '_SelectedSchoolList' is updated/changed
```

My class:

```
  class SelectedSchoolList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SelectedStudentList> SelectedStudentArray { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public class SelectedStudentList
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string IndividualScore { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `PropertyChanged` is an event.  You handle it like you do any other event.

Comment: Define "if any of data changed", and show assignment code, please.

Comment: please see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

First, you have some errors to fix in your implementation. You have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface properly.

Take the `SchoolName` property for example, if you set it with a new value, the `PropertyChanged` event will not fired at all, which means the UI will not be updated to reflect the change.

```
class SelectedSchoolList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    //... other code omitted
}
```

You should fire the `PropertyChanged` event in the property's setter. And do this to all the properties that you use in binding.

**Q: I want to call another function (ex: CallIfValueChanged();) if any of data changed in this observable collection.**

You can register an event handler to `_SelectedSchoolList`'s [CollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/ms653375.aspx) event, which is fired

> when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

Call your method in the event handler.

Comment: How to write collectionchanged event under my code? my class and code are in two different pages.

Comment: You don't need to change the code in `My class`, just add this line in `My code`: `_SelectedSchoolList.CollectionChanged += CallIfValueChanged;`.

Comment: it shows : "cant implicitly convert type void to system.collections.specialised.notifycollectionchangedeventhandler"

Answer (score 0):

Try add private field for each public property, `NotifyPropertyChanged` method to your class. Then change setter and getter. Ex:

```
class SelectedSchoolList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _schoolName;
   private string _score;

   public string SchoolName 
   { 
       get => _schoolName; 
       set { _schoolName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
   }
   public string Score 
   { 
       get => _score; 
       set { _score = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
   }
   public ObservableCollection<SelectedStudentList> SelectedStudentArray{ get; set;}

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
 }
```

Finally, add a method to `CollectionChanged` event of `_SelectedSchoolList`:

```
_SelectedSchoolList.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { CallIfValueChanged(); };
```

Comment: what should be this  (sender, e) parameters?

Comment: It is a lambda expression. Read more: [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). (sender, e) is a function with out name and has 2 parameter: `(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)`. `{ CallIfValueChanged(); }` is the function's body and he function will return `void`.

Comment: You can replace it with a function like:
         `private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
         {
                 CallIfValueChanged();
         }`

Comment: ok, In case of if I'm using multiple observable collections - Then , how can i identify which observable collection is changed

Comment: You can take it with `object sender` by: `var collection = (sender as ObserverbalCollection<SelectedSchoolList>);`. `sender` is the object has property was changed.

Comment: private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) { CallIfValueChanged(); }  this function is not firing when value changes in data

Comment: Make sure you have `NotifyPropertyChanged` function in setter of property changed.

Comment: yes , control goes to NotifyPropertyChanged function . But not going to OnCollectionChanged function which is written on my Main Page

Comment: I'm sorry. The `CollectionChanged` just can invoke when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed. If you want to do somethings when each item's data is changed, you must add a function to event `PropertyChanged` of each item. You can follow [my code](https://codepad.co/snippet/PHrUpNOQ)